# Integrate Tesseract OCR engine in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, ocr, tesseract

I am integrated Tessertact Engine in iOS. I used the following tutorial for integration. My code having no error [use-tesseract](http://lois.di-qual.net/blog/install-and-use-tesseract-on-ios-with-tesseract-ios/)

but i am getting the following error when i run the application [image]

Answer (score 0):

According with your error.

The file is being compiled instead of being copied to output bundle.

Therefore, make sure that in project settings file just copied, not compiled.

Also select that file & make its property as text file, or pure data - in such case it wouldn't be processed by external tool.

Comment: what does it means i can not got u

Comment: lm - is an extension that is processed by xcode's tool. The file is being compiled, instead of just being copied into bundle